# How to send Push Notification using OneSignal in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, onesignal

I've followed the guide in OneSignal's documetation, i've setup the sdk and everything, yet, sending a notificaion **through code** seems to not work at all, not by a specific tag and not by "All Users" segment example which OneSignal provided in their documentation. 
Tho, through their dashboard- it works perfectly.
I've doubled checked all the grandle setup part and stil...
Any idea why that can be happening? what should I check next?

(I didn't attach my code here cause it's an exact copy of OneSignal's code in their documentation)

Thank :)

EDIT: i've noticed that when I send push notification through code- it isn't being shown in the OneSignal's dashboard. So it means something is wrong with the code, tho again, it is similar the the one inside thier documentation (except that i've changed there the ONESIGNAL APP ID
 and REST API KEY, as they requested).
Any ideas? tnx.

Comment: Just check, is your device is listed in OneSignal's user segment?

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit yes.

Comment: Which Android version are you using?, sometimes notification comes late.

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit   please look at the "EDIT" section i've added.